# Techniques to count nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, network, peers, ethernodes

What are the different techniques to count nodes in ethereum? ethernodes.org has a count of nodes, how can we verify if that is true ?
Are there any other techniques to do similar counting. Can you please list/link them.